# Proper Prepare Statement for ALTER TABLE and using AFTER

Tags: plugin-development, wpdb

My code for `ALTER TABLE` doesn't make use of the `prepare()` method of `$wpdb` and so the code needs to be updated properly. There are plenty of examples of query `SELECT`, etc but couldn't find something for `ALTER TABLE` with several options included in the SQL.

This is the old code.

```
$post_qry = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts" );

if ( ! isset( $post_qry->forum_id ) ) {
    $wpdb->query( "ALTER TABLE {$wpdb->posts} ADD `forum_id` INT( 10 )
        UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' AFTER `ID` " );
}
```

This is my first attempt, but something doesn't look right for the ADD.

```
if ( ! isset( $post_qry->forum_id ) ) {
    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "ALTER TABLE {$wpdb->posts} ADD col= %s INT( 10 )
        UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' AFTER col = %s ", 'forum_id', 'ID' ) );
}
```

- First, is it proper to use `ADD col =` or is it `ADD COLUMN=%s` ?
- Second, is the same true for stating after `col=%s`?
- Third, should `INT` and `UNSIGNED` be used as `%s` also?

Thank you for your time to explain and maybe point to a [good resource](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks).

Comment: Modifying the posts table to add a `forum_id` is a bad idea, you should use post meta to store values, or use a custom taxonomy if you're trying to organise posts

Comment: I understand but at this point the plugin was written 2.5 years ago and I'm slowly moving it to OOP as well as fix mistakes such as modifying the post table as well as the comments table. For now, I simply need to know a better way to use ALTER TABLE until I can get the code working for post meta.

Comment: Nevermind OOP, you can replace all your SQL queries with `WP_Query` loops and calls to `get_post_meta`, eliminate your table creation and update code entirely, and as a bonus you get a free GUI

Comment: Thank you @TomJNowell -- your comments pushed me to stop altering the table. The key being `update_post_meta ( $post->ID , 'forum_id', $thread_id );` instead of all the mysql code. Retrieving the meta data was just as easy.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to this question actually comes from @TomJNowell. Instead of using MySQL calls, use the native functions included with WordPress:

```
update_post_meta ( $post->ID , 'forum_id', $thread_id );
```

where the `forum_id` is the key and the `$thread_id` is the value. I tried `add_post_meta` but that created duplicates.

To retrieve the meta data

`$thread_id = get_post_custom_values( 'thread_id', $post->ID);`

Now I'm looking at ways to add to the comment meta. Hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: This sounds like a much better plan than modifying core tables.